# laravel how to handle third party API Http::post error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-6

im new in laravel im using Third Party API for sending sms notification, but Third Party API having some Down time so i need to refresh page ONCE OR TWISE to send notification,  i that time  get error on my website.

i need to auto send second attempt if get error and i dont what to show error in my site.

**Error Im Getting**

```
Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException
cURL error 28: Failed to connect to api.gateway.in port 80: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

**My controller**

```
public function Store_Enrollment(Request $request)

    {

      $this->validate($request, [

  'student_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'phone_no' => 'required|string|max:10',
         
    ]);
 
   $input['student_name'] = ucfirst ($request['student_name']);
   $input['phone_no'] = $request->phone_no;
   $redirect = Student::create($input); 
 
  
Http::post("http://api.gateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=XXX&password=XXX&mobile=$redirect->phone_no&message=thank you $redirect->name,"); 

 return redirect('home' . thank you);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP client has a `retry` function, so you could do the following:

```
Http::retry(3, 30)->post("some_stuff");
```

where the 1st parameter is the number of retries and the 2nd are the seconds between the retries which is optional.

So the above will retry 3 times with 30 seconds in between the requests.

You may don't want to throw an error but you can't retring for eternity so i'd suggest to use a `try` and `catch` block so the app can fail gracefully. Error handling is a big deal.